# On WP7 & Computer, Playing first playlist Item automatically using SMF (Silverlight Media Framework)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, video-streaming, wowza, mmppf

I currently have a SmoothStreaming video comming from a Wowza server and We are currently using the SMF to play the video on the Windows Phone 7 and on the computer. We are adding the Manifest to the playlist and setting it to

```
PlaylistItem { DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming };
```

The problem we are currently facing, is that even if the player is set on AutoPlay="True", the video will not start on it's own. We must open the play list in the player and select the first video for it to start playing.

we have also tried to the CurrentPlaylistItem, but this has not changed anything.

has anyone dealt with smoothstreaming from a Wowza Server? Can someone shed some light on this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to play a video on the Windows Phone 7 using the  SMF (Silverlight Media Framework) it is important to know that a H.264/MPEG-4 video will not play in the emulator, and will not play if the device is connected to the computer. The video will play only if the device is connected via WIFI or 3G.

Further more, be sure to have the latest version of the SMF. It was reported that binding the CurrentPlaylistItem does not work on certain versions. A quick solution to this problem, is to make the binding in code and not in xaml.